# foreach loop works but while doesnt do it

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, while-loop

normally id use foreach for this. but i also need something thats increasing with 1 each time it spins through it. which is why i use a while loop. but i cant get it to work at all.
the foreach loop is working fine. but when i apply the while loop it doesnt do anything, or just create an infinite amount of rows being displayed. so im searching for some help. probably a really easy solution but i cant see it.

```
$SQL = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, title, img_src, rating FROM movie_db ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
$SQL->execute();
$r = $SQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//while($r = $row){
foreach($r as $row){


//$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error());

$i = 1;
//while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$img_src = $row['img_src'];
$rating = $row['rating'];


                    if ($i<=2){echo"<div class='featured_post left'>";}
                    elseif ($i=3){echo"<div class='featured_post left featured_post_last'>";}
                    $i++;
```

i also tried it with a do-while loop but then i couldnt get the result to display at all, but it used the right code atleast then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORDER BY RAND()` is not very efficient.  I suggest instead:

```
$qry = $pdo->query('
  SELECT id, title, img_src, rating, @lim := @lim - 1
  FROM   movie_db, (SELECT @cnt := COUNT(*)+1, @lim := 3 FROM movie_db) init
  WHERE  RAND() < @lim / (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
  LIMIT  3
');
```

As for your problem:

```
for($i = 1; $row = $qry->fetch(); $i = $i<2 ? $i+1 : 0) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $title = $row['title'];
  $img_src = $row['img_src'];
  $rating = $row['rating'];

  echo '<div class="featured_post left', ($i ? '' : ' featured_post_last'), '">';
}
```

Comment: it works fine. thanks! but could you explain to me what the first part does? because i really dont understand what "@cnt", "@lim" etc does and what the rest of the code really do exept randomize something

Comment: @saknarnamn: `@cnt` and `@lim` are MySQL [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html), updated by MySQL as the query is executed.  See @Quassnoi's blog article, [Selecting random rows](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/) for a detailed description of how that query works.

Answer (score 0):

`elseif ($i=3)` shoud be `elseif ($i==3)`

i.e

```
            if ($i<=2){echo"<div class='featured_post left'>";}
            elseif ($i==3){echo"<div class='featured_post left featured_post_last'>";}
            $i++;
```